# How do I convert <oauth:authorization-server> to Java Config?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-java-config

I believe that all of these are simply using default values, we're using jdbc for our token store, client details is the default variant for that. Looks like we have a custom userApprovalHandler.

```
<oauth:authorization-server 
    client-details-service-ref="clientDetails"
    token-services-ref="tokenServices"
    user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
    <oauth:client-credentials />
    <oauth:password authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"/>
</oauth:authorization-server>
```

I know we have to add `@EnableAuthorizationServer` but I'm not sure if I actually need to implement `AuthorizationServerConfigurer` or if since these all have annotations if spring can figure it out (it does that sometimes)? I'm also unsure what the right way to set some of these is. For example I haven't found the spot to set `client-credentials`, or `password`. I'm not really sure how they translate.

this is what I've come up with so far

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2Config implements AuthorizationServerConfigurer
{
    @Autowired private ClientDetailsService clientDetails;
    @Autowired private AuthorizationServerTokenServices tokenServices;


    @Override
    public void configure( final AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security ) throws Exception
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void configure( final ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients ) throws Exception
    {
        clients.withClientDetails( clientDetails );
    }

    @Override
    public void configure( final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints ) throws Exception
    {
        endpoints.tokenServices( tokenServices );
    }
}
```

Because this seems like a small snippet and the java config shouldn't be much bigger if you could supply a complete configuration class example with these options that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Pls find below a sample code for it :-

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    public class OAuth2CustomConfig extends
            AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Bean
        public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter() {
            JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
            KeyPair keyPair = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(new ClassPathResource(
                    "keystore.jks"), "foo".toCharArray()).getKeyPair("bar");
            converter.setKeyPair(keyPair);
            return converter;
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer)
                throws Exception {
            oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess(
                    "isAuthenticated()");
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients)
                throws Exception {
            clients.inMemory()
                    .withClient("xxxx")
                    .secret("xxxxsecret")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code",
                            "refresh_token", "password").scopes("openid");
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
                throws Exception {
            endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                    .accessTokenConverter(jwtAccessTokenConverter());
        }

    }
```